# Outlook 365 On Line: No "recall message" feature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

It appears outlook 365 web version lacks "recall message"?

How is this possible?

(Many consider this a mission critical feature, and outlook desktop has it.)

I should add that the "undo send" feature in outlook 365 is dangerous and should be eliminated. Here is why:

1) It only allows up to 30 seconds of undo, that is not useful.

2) It delays the email from showing up on the thread or in Sent. Super confusing. I sent some emails, and could not find them.... they were lost!  Oh, it is the undo thing. So I went and turned off the undo send option.

3) The big sin is that the send email experience is trashed. Normally I see emails I send appear at the top of the thread. But with the undo feature enabled, my emails disappear, and do NOT appear at top of thread for 30 seconds. Panic!  Not OK to mess with the look and feel of the main behavior of the app.

Comment: This is how this feature was designed. Obviously, it cannot meet all people's needs. You may let Microsoft know your concerns via posting to the UserVoice forum: https://office365.uservoice.com/

Comment: @SteveFan Thanks for the note!  I do not use the MS channels for interaction, having tried a few of them and had unproductive experiences.